# How to sync only my latest commit with git?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push

My local repository is ahead of remote by 2 commits - commit A and commit B.

Commit A was made first, and contains a very large file by accident, which is too large to stage and is causing a failure on `push`.

So, I deleted the file, untracked it, and then made commit B. However, I cannot `push` commit B, because then both commit A and B are attempting to `push`, which leads to commit A causing the same failure before B can be pushed.

Is there any way to tell git to ignore the first of these two commits? Or to "delete" commit A?

Comment: `git reset HEAD~2` and start again, maybe? Understand that git models your commits as a graph, and the child B cannot be pushed without its parent A also being in the history, so you need to recreate B (let's call it B') *from A's parent*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can reset all commits and start again, with a clean stack.

- `git reset --soft HEAD~2` and then `git commit -am "cleaned commit"`.

Comment: Maybe you can reset all commits and start again, with a clean stack. ´git reset --soft HEAD~2´ and then ´git commit -am "cleaned commit"´.

Comment: This worked. Simple and easy, thanks. If you make this comment an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I had to revisit this question and would like to know, what is the function of the `~2`?

Comment: It means two commits backward.

Answer (score 3):

Another choice is `git rebase -i HEAD^^`.  If you squash commits A and B together, there will be no record in the resulting commit of the offending file.  This approach will also give you a chance to recycle some of your original commit message for commit A into the new resulting commit, if you desire.

Comment: The above command opens the rebase text file, and that's all. I don't know what to do with it. What do you mean when you say to "squash them together"?

Comment: @jphollowed in this case if `git rebase` is confusing, you could try `git reset HEAD^^ --soft && git commit`. The command squashes A and B to a single commit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cherry-pick`.

Assuming your remote branch is `master` and your branch with both commits is `master-plus-a-and-b`:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b master-plus-b
git cherry-pick master-plus-a-and-b
```

Now `master-plus-b` has only `master`'s commits and commit b, not commit a. You may have to cleanup any conflicts during the `cherry-pick` process.